# How do I make another action repeat inside a loop?

Tags: arduino-uno, led, button, code-review, loop

*So, I've just started programming Arduino (and also in general), so I'm doing basic things, like switching on and off LED's.*

I've made them light in a sequence and then turning them off (in the same sequence), and now I wanted to use 2 buttons, one to make them do the same thing as before (light and turning LED's off in sequence) repeatedly, and the other to turn them off.

The problem is that curently they only light up once, and not repeatedly, I think I would've needed another loop, but i found out that you can't use 2 of them.

Can anyone help me? here's the code

```
int LED1 = 2;
int LED2 = 3;
int LED3 = 4;
int LED4 = 5;
int LED5 = 6;
int buttonON = 7;
int buttonOFF = 8;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonON, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonOFF, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop ()
{
  if (digitalRead(buttonON)== LOW)
  {
    delay(300), digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
    delay(50), digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
    delay(50), digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
    delay(50), digitalWrite(LED4, HIGH);
    delay(50), digitalWrite(LED5, HIGH);
    delay(300), digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    delay(100), digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
    delay(100), digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
    delay(100), digitalWrite(LED4, LOW);
    delay(100), digitalWrite(LED5, LOW);
  }
 if (digitalRead(buttonOFF)== LOW)
 {
  digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED5, LOW);
 }
}
```

P.S. if anyone has other general tips I would really apreciate them

Comment: insert a layer of separation between the button press and the LED lighting ... use a flag variable .... `if (digitalRead(buttonON)== LOW)  ledsON = true;` .... then further down in the code `if (ledsON) { / led lighting code }` ... you can set/clear `ledsON` flag any number of times, so you could check the button after every led is lit ... that way you don't have to hold the button until the sequence is finished

Comment: good way of asking question ;) Nicely written, formatted +1

Comment: I take it you are new to programming?

Comment: yes, like i said, I've just started, and decided to start programming with Arduino

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have written your question beautifully.
In your case, according to your logic, the button has to be kept pressed, so that the LEDs are lit in the order you desire. The single loop() function is part of the Arduino sketch but it is never a limitation.

One way to solve your problem is to make the LED drive logic independent of the button press state.

- Once you detect the button press, store the event in one variable.
- Let us call it `ButtonStatus`.
- So, soon after the keypress is detected, update the `ButtonStatus` variable to TRUE.
- Your LED drive logic can check this variable value to decide whether to drive the LEDs or not
- Soon after you detect another press of the second button, you can update the variable value to FALSE.
  Here is the Arduino simulation output for your code and the code suggested by @cat

[image]

below is after adapting the solution from cat
[image]

The simulation links are here:
[Original problem](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/304627808095699521)
[solution 1](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/304626706673566272)

```
int LED1 = 2;
int LED2 = 3;
int LED3 = 4;
int LED4 = 5;
int LED5 = 6;
int buttonON = 7;
int buttonOFF = 8;
int ledEffectON;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonON, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonOFF, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop ()
{
  if (digitalRead(buttonON)== LOW)
      ledEffectON = true;

  if (digitalRead(buttonOFF)== LOW)
      ledEffectON = false;

  if(ledEffectON)
  {
    delay(300), digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
    delay(50), digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
    delay(50), digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
    delay(50), digitalWrite(LED4, HIGH);
    delay(50), digitalWrite(LED5, HIGH);
    delay(300), digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    delay(100), digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
    delay(100), digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
    delay(100), digitalWrite(LED4, LOW);
    delay(100), digitalWrite(LED5, LOW);
  }
}
```

Link to docs on [Pushbuttons](https://docs.wokwi.com/parts/wokwi-pushbutton). Wokwi Arduino simulator simulates debounce by default - just like real-world switched. Debounce is a very important technique that you should consider adding to the code. To disable the "bounce" option, use the below trick!

```
{ "bounce": "0" }
```

Comment: Thanks, really apreciate the time you spent on explaining it

Comment: Very nice diagrams!

Comment: @Juraj brought in resistors. I have also updated the links referred to. Now you should see the current limiting resistors as well!

Answer (score 6):

By using `delay()` it blocks the rest of the code. The programme needs to keep track of two buttons and update the lightshow at appropriate times, therefore a non-blocking style of coding is needed similar to the [Blink Without Delay example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/BlinkWithoutDelay/) where the `delay()` is replaced with a timer using `millis()` that is checked periodically. This allows other things to be checked periodically as well, e.g. the buttons.

Also the button contacts tend to bounce several times for several milliseconds when they change state sending a train of on/off pulses to the MCU, so they need to be debounced. You can find many debouncing algorithms online, but here's a [simple debouncer](https://github.com/TimMathias/Arduino-Debouncer) that I put on GitHub.

```cpp
void loop ()
{
  static bool doLightshow = false;

  static Debouncer buttonOn(buttonON);
  static Debouncer buttonOff(buttonOFF);

  buttonOn.Update();
  buttonOff.Update();

  if (buttonOn.Fall())
  {
    Serial.println("buttonOn falling edge.");
    doLightshow = true;
  }
  else if (buttonOff.Fall())
  {
    Serial.println("buttonOff falling edge.");
    doLightshow = false;
  }

  if (doLightshow)
  {
    // Do lightshow.
    . . .
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED4, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED5, LOW);
  }
}
```

Due to the way you've neatly written your code, you can probably pick out a pattern in the lightshow.

| State | Delay time | LED pin | LED state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 300 | LED1 | HIGH |
| 1 | 50 | LED2 | HIGH |
| 2 | 50 | LED3 | HIGH |
| 3 | 50 | LED4 | HIGH |
| 4 | 50 | LED5 | HIGH |
| 5 | 300 | LED1 | LOW |
| 6 | 100 | LED2 | LOW |
| 7 | 100 | LED3 | LOW |
| 8 | 100 | LED4 | LOW |
| 9 | 100 | LED5 | LOW |

This lends itself well to creating a Finite State Machine that can be stored in an array of structures:

```cpp
typedef struct LightshowData
{
  unsigned int delayTime;
  byte ledPin;
  bool ledState;
};

const byte numStates = 10;

const LightshowData lightshowData[numStates] =
{
  { 300, LED1, HIGH },
  {  50, LED2, HIGH },
  {  50, LED3, HIGH },
  {  50, LED4, HIGH },
  {  50, LED5, HIGH },
  { 300, LED1, LOW },
  { 100, LED2, LOW },
  { 100, LED3, LOW },
  { 100, LED4, LOW },
  { 100, LED5, LOW }
};
```

The state machine can now cycle through the array in a non-blocking manner:

```cpp
    // Do lightshow.
    static byte state = 0;
    unsigned long currentTimestamp = millis();
    static unsigned long previousTimestamp = currentTimestamp;

    if (currentTimestamp - previousTimestamp >= lightshowData[state].delayTime)
    {
      previousTimestamp += lightshowData[state].delayTime;
      digitalWrite(lightshowData[state].ledPin, lightshowData[state].ledState);
      state = ++state % numStates;
      Serial.print("state = ");
      Serial.println(state);
    }
```

You may want to reset `state` to 0 after a negative edge on `buttonOff`, otherwise the lightshow will continue where it left off after being stopped and restarted.

Here's the Wokwi simulation of the lightshow with 250 Ω protection resistors for the LEDs.

[image]

[Wokwi simulates button bounce by default](https://docs.wokwi.com/parts/wokwi-pushbutton#bouncing) to more accurately model the real world, so it's advisable to have some form of button debouncing.

Comment: thanks man, looks a bit difficult, but I'll certanly check it out

Comment: When the loop() function does not need any time ( avoid delay and nested time consuming loops ) your program logic is completely different from before, but more flexible and easier, once you got used to it.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to save the state of the LEDs in a new variable ...

```
void loop ()
{
  if (digitalRead(buttonON)== LOW)
      ledEffectON = true;

  if (digitalRead(buttonOFF)== LOW)
      ledEffectON = false;

  if(ledEffectON)
  {
    delay(300), digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
    delay(50), digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
    delay(50), digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
    delay(50), digitalWrite(LED4, HIGH);
    delay(50), digitalWrite(LED5, HIGH);
    delay(300), digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    delay(100), digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
    delay(100), digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
    delay(100), digitalWrite(LED4, LOW);
    delay(100), digitalWrite(LED5, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/304626706673566272 Wonderful solution!

Comment: Thanks for the short and simple answer

Comment: It's very seldom that  buttonOFF is checked. It needs to be pressed when LED5 goes LOW

Comment: is this not the same code as in ArduinoFan's answer?